# How to display size legend in bubble chart?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a bubble chart with color defined as measure 1. Size is defined as measure 2. Text is defines as attribute 1.

When I drag the worksheet to the dashboard and select the drop down from the worksheet and hover over legends. I see the Color legend activated but the Size grayed out. How can I display the size legend?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer, unfortunately, is that you cannot show the size legend for packed bubble charts.

Only if you were to place a dimension, for instance, in the Columns or Rows shelf, would the legend for size would become available. I don't think that offers much help for your visualization, though.

[image]

Becomes:

[image]

---

This is the best information I could find on this: https://community.tableau.com/thread/126259

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the size legend, you have to have selected a measure that controls the size of the visual.

On the Marks pane, click the arrow next to one of your measures and select "Size" as the mark
Now you should be able to enable the size legend (Analysis > Legends > Size Legend)

If you already have a measure selected for size, try removing the measure and re-adding it.

Comment: I already have that setup but the option to select the size legend is grayed out